# Timer on slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I set up a slideshow to show like this:

J/S:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {        
            var count = $(".slider_class").length;

            var i=0;
            while (i < count){
              $(".slider_bullets").append('<a href="#" id="bullet_link_' + i +'" class="slider_bullet_btn"></a>');
              $(".slider_bullets a").click(function(){ $(".slider_class").hide(); $("#slide_"+$(this).index()).show(); });              
              $(".slider_bullets a").click(function(){ $(".slider_bullet_btn").removeClass("selected_bullet"); });
              $(".slider_bullets a").click(function(){ $(this).addClass("selected_bullet"); });

              i++;
             }
            $("#slide_0").show();
            $("#bullet_link_0").addClass("selected_bullet");
        });
        </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slide_0" class="slider_class">
            <div class="slider_profile_info"><h2>John Smith</h2><p>Phasellus at libero sem, non sodales velit. Proin vitae metus sed diam euismod tempus. In varius diam ut enim adipiscing aliquet.</p><img src="img/learn_more.jpg" alt="learn_more" width="152" height="35" class="learn_more_btn" /></div><div class="slider_profile_img"><img src="img/slider_overlay.png" alt="slider_overlay" width="710" height="359" /></div>
            </div>


            <div id="slide_1" class="slider_class">
            <div class="slider_profile_info"><h2>John Smith</h2><p>Phasellus at libero sem, non sodales velit. Proin vitae metus sed diam euismod tempus. In varius diam ut enim adipiscing aliquet.</p><img src="img/learn_more.jpg" alt="learn_more" width="152" height="35" class="learn_more_btn" /></div><div class="slider_profile_img"><img src="img/slider_overlay.png" alt="slider_overlay" width="710" height="359" /></div>
            </div>


            <div id="slide_2" class="slider_class">
            <div class="slider_profile_info"><h2>John Smith</h2><p>Phasellus at libero sem, non sodales velit. Proin vitae metus sed diam euismod tempus. In varius diam ut enim adipiscing aliquet.</p><img src="img/learn_more.jpg" alt="learn_more" width="152" height="35" class="learn_more_btn" /></div><div class="slider_profile_img"><img src="img/slider_overlay.png" alt="slider_overlay" width="710" height="359" /></div>
            </div><div class="slider_bullets"></div>
```

But now I'd like to add a timer to cycle through all of the different slides. I know how to accomplish this with a fixed number of slides but I can't imagine how I would handle it with an unknown number of slides. I tried using setInterval but I couldn't figure out how to get the next slide ID in a progression in order to display it. Any ideas?

Comment: $(".slider_bullets") there is no element with this class in your HTML...

Comment: the answer i gave you only takes into account the timer for changing, not the actions of buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
        var count = $(".slider_class").length;
        $("#slide_0").show();
        var currentSlide = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
           if (++currentSlide > count)
              currentSlide = 1;
            console.log(currentSlide);
           $('.slider_class').hide();
           $('.slider_class:nth-child(' + currentSlide + ')').show();
        }, 1000);
    });
```

this would work for whatever count of slides you have

Comment: This successfully hides the first slide but if fails to show the next one. It returns this error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('.slider_class').hide().index(currentSlide).show()')

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez if i wanted to add a slider scroll function so i can change between slides. How do i implement it with the above code

Comment: @Vishnu667, what do you mean by a slider scroll function? a next and a previous button?

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez like changing the contents within the slider class based on a action or a button click like a slider

Comment: @Vishnu667 that would be a completely different thing, i'll try to do that in a fiddle